# Sampling pixels from an Image - increasing performance

Tags: performance, matlab

I am sampling some pixels from a reference image `Ir` and then moving them on a secondary image `In`. The first function I have written is as follows:

```
[r,c,d] = size(Ir);
rSample = fix(r * 0.4);         % sample 40 percent of pixels
cSample = fix(c * 0.4);         % sample 40 percent of pixels
rIdx = randi(r,rSample,1);       % uniformly sample indices for rows
cIdx = randi(c,cSample,1);       % uniformly sample indices for columns
kk = 1;
for ii = 1:length(rIdx)
    for jj=1:length(cIdx)
        In(rIdx(ii),cIdx(jj),:) = Ir(rIdx(ii),cIdx(jj),:) * fcn(rIdx(ii),cIdx(jj));
        kk = kk + 1;
    end
end
```

Another method to increase the performance (speed) of the code, that I came around is as follows:

```
nSample = fix(r*c*0.4);
Idx = randi(r*c,nSample,1);
for ii = 1:nSample
    [I,J] = ind2sub([r,c],Idx(ii,1));
    In(I,J,:) = Ir(I,J,:) * fcn(I,J);
end
```

In both codes, `fcn(I,J)` is a function that performs some computation on the pixel at `[I,J]` and the process can be different depending on the indices of the pixel. 
Although I have removed one `for-loop`, I guess there is a better technique to increase the performance of the code even more.

Update:

As suggested by @Daniel the following line of the code does the job.

```
In(rIdx,cIdx,:)=Ir(rIdx,cIdx,:);
```

But the point is, I prefer to have only the sampled pixels to be able to process them faster. For instance having the samples in a vector format wit 3 layers for RGB.

```
Io = Ir(rIdx,cIdx,:);
Io1 = Io(:,:,1);
Io1v = Io1(:);
```

Comment: `Undefined function or variable 'rSample'.` for the first and `Undefined function 'sampleIdx' for input
arguments of type 'double'.` for the second example code. First is clear how to fix, second not really.

Comment: Now both versions are working, but implementing a different pattern. Try it with `In=ones(r,c,d)` and `Ir=In*0`. First code always generates a pattern of white stripes.

Comment: I don't understand your update. Doesn't it already contain the solution? `Io = Ir(rIdx,cIdx,:);`

Comment: @Daniel I updated the question and I see it is going stupidly coz I could not explain the whole problem in advance. Sorry, I prefer not to go further anymore. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Ir=ones(30,30,3);
In=Ir*.5;
[r,c,d] = size(Ir);
rSamples = fix(r * 0.4);         % sample 40 percent of pixels
cSamples = fix(c * 0.4);         % sample 40 percent of pixels
rIdx = randi(r,rSamples,1);       % uniformly sample indices for rows
cIdx = randi(c,cSamples,1);       % uniformly sample indices for columns
In(rIdx,cIdx,:)=Ir(rIdx,cIdx,:);
```